# Sort deck of cards with least no of moves

Tags: algorithms, sorting

We have n cards with each card numbered from 1 to n.

All cards are randomly shuffled but all cards are visible

We are allowed only operation MoveCard(n) which moves the card with value n to the top of the pile.

We need to sort the pile of cards with minimum number of MoveCard operations.

The brute force approach which i can think of is start with MoveCard(n), MoveCard(n-1), MoveCard(n-2).... MoveCard(1).

This approach will solve the problem in n MoveCard operations.

But can we optimize it.

For instance, If the input is like: 3 1 4 2

As per my approach:

```
4 3 1 2 
3 4 1 2
2 3 4 1
1 2 3 4
```

MoveCard operations is 4.

But we can solve this problem with minimum number of moves:

Optimized solution is:

```
2 3 1 4 
1 2 3 4
```

MoveCard operations is 2.

The aim is to find the first card which has to be moved. In this case its 2

Comment: Hint: Consider all of the cards that you never call MoveCard on.  Where will they end up, in the final configuration?  If you underline those numbers in the initial configuration, do you see a pattern?  What order do they have to be in?  What does this imply for your problem?

Comment: Hint: you can mention that some subsequences can be already sorted. And among all such subsequences you can leave some untouched subsequnce and do $MoveCard$ operation only for another cards. It will save some moves.

Comment: What' s the original source for this question?  This question appears to be copied from http://stackoverflow.com/q/21852309/781723, without attribution or credit.  That constitutes plagiarism, which isn't welcome here.  Please consult our guidelines on how to reference material written by others, and edit the question to follow them: http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a permutation $\pi:[n]\to[n]$ of cards from $1$ to $n$ you can find the first card to move to the front the following way:

1. $c \leftarrow n$
2. for each $k$ from $n$ down to $1$ do
3. $\space\space\space$ if $c = \pi(k)$ then
4. $\space\space\space\space\space\space$ $c \leftarrow c - 1$
5. $\space\space\space$ end if
6. end for
7. return $c$

In other words, choose the highest card, for which there is another card of higher value in front of it. More formally, choose a maximum $c\in[n]$ such that there exists a $c' > c$ with $\pi(k') = c'$, $\pi(k) = c$ and $k' < k$. Clearly, this card is not in order yet and since it is the one with the highest value it must be moved first if we want to keep the number of moves minimal. For the permutation $3,1,4,2$ this card is clearly card number $2$.

Comment: So, selection sort. Why would that be *optimal*?

Answer (score -2):

use [Count sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

```
for x in input:
    count[key(x)] += 1

# calculate the starting index for each key:
total = 0
for i in range(k):   # i = 0, 1, ... k-1
    oldCount = count[i]
    count[i] = total
    total += oldCount

# copy to output array, preserving order of inputs with equal keys:
for x in input:
    output[count[key(x)]] = x
    count[key(x)] += 1

return output
```

sorry about that. in that case you can pick the first greatest card which is smaller than the top card and move it to top. with this the above example i.e. 4 3 1 2 can be done in three steps and this one 2 3 1 4 in ONE step..

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question. It doesn't use `MoveCard()` at all. And, anyway, you know you started with a deck of cards numbered $1, \dots, n$. There's no point using a sorting algorithm: you already know exactly what the sorted output is.

Comment: sorry about that.
in that case you can pick the first greatest card which is smaller than the top card and move it to top. with this the above example i.e. 4 3 1 2 can be done in three steps and this one 2 3 1 4  in ONE step..